# How can I launch an external website in JQuery Mobile without leaving the app?

Tags: iframe, jquery-mobile, web, dialog, external

I'm working on a PhoneGap+JQM app that allows the operator to view our website.  If we do a normal target="_blank", it launches Safari but doesn't provide an easy way to return to the app.

Has anyone figured out a good way to launch an external website in JQM in a dialog or with a closeable header?  So far I've stuffed an iframe into a dialog and it is sorta working, but it feels a bit klugey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out..
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

works fine for loading external link, within the app

Comment: I appreciate it, but I'm coding for Android/iPhone/Palm.  I can't use device specific libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Use [dialogs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html). It acts as a popup in which you can add any content you want. User can close the popup and return back to your application. It won't feel nice unless the external website is designed for mobile devices.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm trying a simple test, like <a href="http://www.cnn.com" data-rel="dialog">Test External Website</a>, but clicking the link takes over the browser instead of launching a dialog with a header.  Am I missing a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Using a header with a back button and an iframe with the external site works great for me. You could also have a button in the header called 'Exit' or something like that that takes you to another JQM page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageExternalSite" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>example.com</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PhoneGap now has a native InApp Browser, so my original post is somewhat invalidated.  I kind of want to try your iFrame approach, however.  The InApp Browser doesn't render pages as accurate as a normal browser.  I also can't communicate to the page within the window.  I'm not sure I could using an iframe either, but at least I'd have a chance.